# What does -q and -O mean?

Tags: wget, cron

What does -q and -O mean in the following cronjob?

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/moodle/admin/cron.php
```

Comment: "ServerFault: We will RTFM so that you won't need to!" \*sigh\*

Comment: This is now the number 1 result for UTFG "wget q"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are actually options for the `wget` command and not to do with `cron`'s operation.

`-q` tells `wget` to operate quietly (ie. to not output the usual status information)
`-O /dev/null` tells it to output to `/dev/null`

Type `man wget` for more info on `wget`'s operation and options.

Comment: if we you want to output to STDOUT just  replace  "/dev/null"  to dash symbol  "-"

Answer (score 7):

You can find this in [wget manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).
-O is the location where the file is save, here the file will be trashed
-q is to suppress console output